# Where is the grouped list of classes in the Qt Documentation?

Tags: c++, qt, documentation

In previous versions of Qt, there used to be a list of classes grouped by function (e.g. http://doc.trolltech.com/4.1/groups.html).  This was very useful when looking for a class to perform a function but not knowing the name of the class.  For example, there's a short list of basic widgets at http://doc.trolltech.com/4.1/basic.html.  The "All Classes" list can be somewhat daunting to look through!

However, since the documentation has been reformatted and moved over to http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest I've been unable to find this list and have had to rely on old versions of the documentation.

Does it still exist and if so please can you tell me where it resides?  http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/basic.html gives a 404, whilst http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/groups.html has a list of groups, but most of the old groups are missing (there aren't even any GUI widgets).

Comment: This seems to have been a changed that occurred between 4.5 (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.5/groups.html) and 4.6 (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/groups.html).

Comment: The way I used it was to go through the examples for what you want, then you look up the classes that are in that example. There are so many examples, and they probably have a majority of the features that you're looking for.

Comment: A workaround is to use the old version (for instance 4.5) to find the class you are looking for and modify manually the url to direct to the latest (4.7) documentation. There is not that much new classes that have been introduced since and this could be useful in your case.

Comment: @Lohrun: Thanks: this is what I've been doing to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not exactly the same as before but I think it is a pretty good organization.

Starting at the [main index](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/index.html), notice the second section to the left titled **Qt Topics**. The first item, [Programming with Qt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qt-basic-concepts.html) is a close approximation of the former "Grouped Classes"

Clicking on the third item under Qt Topics, [UI Design with Qt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qt-gui-concepts.html), will bring you to a nice grouping of UI elements. The one labeled [Widgets and Layouts](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/widgets-and-layouts.html) will show you widgets grouped by "basic", "advanced", etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/modules.html), and for example [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtgui.html) you get list of gui classes. 
Easy acces to those you can get from links a the top of content of documentation.

Comment: Is that as far as the granularity goes?  In the old documentation, I could get a list of 20 'basic GUI widgets', the list of GUI classes you linked to has 407 classes: it's a lot harder to find things in a list of 407 than a list of 20...